# Android: Pictures taken saving in progress, RecyclerView preview with Glide fails

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, storage, photo, android-glide

I’m making an Android app which, inside one of it activities (called `CameraAvtivity`), makes the user able to shot photos in rapid succession and when the user himself decides to end the photo taking activity he presses on a button to end the `CameraActivity` for being prompted on another activity (let's call it `PreviewActivity` also if in reality is called `MultiPhotoShootingModeActivity`) that previews the photos made; but **previews aren't always showed correctly** because if I shot some photos in rapid succession and then end the `CameraActivity` without waiting several seconds, the Android device hadn't enough time to store photos and when `PreviewActivity` is called, the saving process is still in progress and some previews are not showed.

What I want to do is showing the previews inside `PreviewActivity` when photos saving process is completely ended and the file containing the photo is correctly stored.

`CameraActivity` for taking photos uses Fotoapparat library; then the previews should be showed in `PreviewActivity` inside a `RecyclerView` using Glide library.

In the following photos I’m showing you the result of not waiting enough time after photos are made and waiting enough time (let’s say that for each photo we should wait 3 seconds, so 12 seconds for 4 photos). In the first case I’ve waited 6-7 seconds starting from the first photo taking until quitting the `CameraActivity`, in the second one I’ve waited 15 seconds.

[image: Not waiting enough time]

[image: Waiting enough time]

The part of the code that stores the image taken is the following.

```
private void takePicture() {
    PhotoResult photoResult = fotoapparatSwitcher.getCurrentFotoapparat().takePicture();

    // Adding a sound to the shutter, taken from http://www.solidfiles.com/v/PMmGVvZ6m5mZM
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.camera_shutter);
    mp.start();

    // Creating a filename with the timestamp
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = MainActivity.sUsername.trim() + "_" + "IMAGE_" + timeStamp + "_" + ".jpg";

    // Creating a "non-collision file name" in case of collision with names of previously saved images
    if (imageFileNamesMPSA.contains(imageFileName)) {
        imageFileName = MainActivity.sUsername.trim() + "_" + "IMAGE_" + timeStamp + "_(" + String.valueOf(fCount++) + ")_" + ".jpg";
    } else {
        fCount = 0;
    }

    // Creating the file
    imageFile = new File(storageDirectory,imageFileName);

    // The location is saved into the string imageFileLocation
    String imageFileLocation = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.i(TAG_THIS_CLASS, "Image file location: " + imageFileLocation);

    // Storing file name and location into the corresponding strings
    switch (callingActivity){
        case "SPSA":
            imageFileNameSPSA = imageFileName;
            imageFileLocationsSPSA = imageFileLocation;
            // TODO: end the CameraActivity automatically when finished with photo taking automatically
            // endPictureTakingOnClick();
            break;
        case "MPSA":
            imageFileNamesMPSA.add(imageFileName);
            imageFileLocationsMPSA.add(imageFileLocation);
            break;
    }

    photoResult.saveToFile(imageFile);

    // This method manages what to do when photo saving is finished
    // For now manages the preview in the CameraActivity and the media scanning of the file
    photoResult
            .toBitmap(scaled(0.25f))
            .whenAvailable(new PendingResult.Callback<BitmapPhoto>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(BitmapPhoto result) {

                    // Previewing the photo made
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(result.bitmap);
                    imageView.setRotation(-result.rotationDegrees);

                    // Tell the MediaScanner about the new file so that it is immediately available to the
                    // user via the gallery
                    // TODO: maybe is not coherent to launch the MediaScanner inside here
                    new SingleMediaScanner(getApplicationContext(), imageFile);
                }
            });
}
```

Notice that thanks to the `whenAvailable` method of Fotoapparat (almost at the end of the above part of code) I'm able to know when each photo is completely saved...but when `CameraActivity` is ended `RecyclerView` with his `Adapter` is called immediately (maybe before that the line with `whenAvailable` method is ran) and photos storing process can be still incomplete.

Below here there is the code of the adapter for the RecyclerView I'm using inside the `PreviewActivity`. Take note that `ImageGalleryAdapter` is a class inside the `PreviewActivity`.

```
/**
 * The following class, using an extension with the RecyclerView.Adapter, manages the actions to
 * do on the RecyclerView and allows actions performed by the user
 */
private class ImageGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

    @Override
    public ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Log.i(TAG_THIS_CLASS, "Beginning of ImageGalleryAdapter");

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the layout
        View photoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false);

        ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder = new ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder(photoView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageGalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        PreviewPhotosInGallery previewPhotoInGallery = mPhotosToPreviewInGallery[position];
        ImageView imageView = holder.mPhotoImageView;

        GlideApp.with(mContext)
                .load(previewPhotoInGallery.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_off_red)
                .into(imageView);
    }

    /**
     * The method for giving back the number of items to load as photo.
     */

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mPhotosToPreviewInGallery.length);
    }

    /**
     * The class that assigns a view holder for each Image and checkbox in the RecyclerView.
     */

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        public ImageView mPhotoImageView;
        public CheckBox mPhotoCheckBox;



        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mPhotoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo_iv);
            mPhotoCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo_checkbox);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        /**
         * The method for managing the click on an image.
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            itemSelection(view);
        }

        /**
         * Manages the selection of the items.
         */
        private void itemSelection (View item){
                Log.i(TAG_THIS_CLASS, "getAdapterPosition " + getAdapterPosition());

                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (!item.isSelected()){
                        // Add clicked item to the selected ones
                        selectedItems [position] = true;
                        // Checking the number of items selected
                        int number_of_items_selected = getResult();
                        // Enabling the button multiPSASendPhoto_BTN
                        multiPSASendPhoto_BTN.setEnabled(true);
                        if (number_of_items_selected == 1){
                            multiPSASendPhoto_BTN.setText(R.string.spsm_button_for_sending_photo);
                        }
                        else {
                            multiPSASendPhoto_BTN.setText(R.string.mpsm_button_for_sending_photos);
                        }

                        // Visually highlighting the ImageView
                        item.setSelected(true);
                        mPhotoCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                        mPhotoCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else {
                        // Remove clicked item from the selected ones
                        selectedItems [position] = false;
                        // Checking the number of items selected
                        int number_of_items_selected = getResult();
                        // Disabling the button multiPSASendPhoto_BTN if selectedItems contains no elements
                        if (number_of_items_selected == 0){
                            multiPSASendPhoto_BTN.setEnabled(false);
                            multiPSASendPhoto_BTN.setText(R.string.mpsm_button_for_sending_photos);
                        }
                        else if (number_of_items_selected == 1){
                            multiPSASendPhoto_BTN.setText(R.string.spsm_button_for_sending_photo);
                        }
                        else {
                            multiPSASendPhoto_BTN.setText(R.string.mpsm_button_for_sending_photos);
                        }

                        // Removing the visual highlights on the ImageView
                        item.setSelected(false);
                        mPhotoCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                        mPhotoCheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                Log.i(TAG_THIS_CLASS, "selectedItems " + selectedItems.toString());

            }

        /**
         * This method counts the number of elements selected in the gallery.
         */
        public int getResult() {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i =0;  i< selectedItems.length ; i++) {
                if (selectedItems[i]){
                    count ++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        /**
         * The method for managing the long click on an image.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                PreviewPhotosInGallery previewPhotoInGallery = mPhotosToPreviewInGallery[position];

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PreviewSinglePhotoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PreviewSinglePhotoActivity.EXTRA_PHOTO, previewPhotoInGallery);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            // return true to indicate that the click was handled (if you return false onClick will be triggered too)
            return true;
        }
    }

    private PreviewPhotosInGallery[] mPhotosToPreviewInGallery;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageGalleryAdapter(Context context, PreviewPhotosInGallery[] photosToPreviewInGallery) {
        mContext = context;
        mPhotosToPreviewInGallery = photosToPreviewInGallery;
    }
}
```

Finally, my questions are:

- is it possible to do something that waits until photos are correctly stored to preview them?
- which is the best way to pursue for accomplishing the task already mentioned (for example an AsyncTask or a method I don't know)?
- can I have a code snippet for getting started to the solution?

I know that it is a long question but I made my best to provide it with which I think are the essential information.
Thank you for your time.